# How to Change .popover-content CSS for ui-bootstrap popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I am using the ui-bootstrap popover to list some notifications in my application. 
I am using the uib-popover-template to design the content of the popover.

I would like to change the padding settings for each elements inside the popover.

I have tried using the popover-class attribute, but this just configures the CSS for the overall popover, and not the elements contained inside - this is what the .popover-content CSS class seems to govern.

Here is the html for the popover:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" uib-popover-template="'myNotifications.html'"
        popover-class="my-notifications-popover"></span>
```

Additionally, I don't want to do this just by doing:

```
.popover-content {
     margin: 0px;
}
```

as I  have used popovers in multiple places throughout my application and don't want them all to get their CSS redefined.

Can anyone tell me how to change this in the correct manner? All help much appreciated...

**EDIT 1**: I've tried to do as suggested in the comments by makshh and use CSS selectors to modify the '.popover-content' class. This class is a div contained within the parent '.popover' class.

I tried to do this with the following:

```
.my-notifications-popover {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.my-notifications-popover div {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

This should make the margin-left zero for all child divs of .my-notifications-popover which should be applied to the popover. However it doesn't seem to be applied at all. This approach may not be ideal since it would set the margin for all divs below the popover which I may not want. Is there a way to specifically target the .popover-content class specifically using the CSS selectors?

I've created a plnkr to show exactly how this is not working.... You can see it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lr43L5b0YUbZEa5Zkvso

Comment: What's the problem of using `my-notifications-popover` class to style your inner elements?

Comment: that seems to only style the outer .popover class

Comment: Yes but for example if you have `h3` tag in your popover content you can style it using `.my-notifications-popover h3` selector.

Comment: just modify the popover container template https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/popover/popover-template.html

Comment: So what would be code to do that? I tried: .my-notifications-popover > .popover-content { margin-left: 0px; } but that didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Added

```
.popover-no-margin .popover-content {
  padding: 0px; 
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/NiIh6qwZiscNZC5ZZrod?p=preview

which works because you passed the custom class

```
popover-class="popover-no-margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like it was padding and not margin that needed to be changed! What a moron... oh well... sorry about that... still not sure what is the most accurate way to target just the popover-content div

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your plunker example.. `.popover-no-margin .popover-content{
  padding:0px;
}` and check if this is what you wanted.
This removes the extra spaces in the popover and it will be applies to this popover only as you have already defined the class `popover-no-margin` for this element.

Answer (score 0):

Just check my code css is reflecting for popover content. You can handle css for popover by adding css to popover-content .popover-line or creating a custom css for popover as popover-class="my-popover-class":

HTML

```
<button popover-class="my-popover-class" popover-placement="right" uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
    <div class="popover-line"> item 1 : This an example of angular ui-bootstrap popover custom content css</div>
    <div class="popover-line"> item 2</div>
    <div class="popover-line"> item 3</div> </script>
```

CSS

```
 .popover-content .popover-line { margin: 10px 0px; } 
.my-popover-class {   color: blue;   padding-left: 0 !important;}
```

Working demo is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hJdLzgA6AkfazqX5DTRX?p=preview)

You can add your css accordingly as you want within .popover-content .popover-line (like color,margin,padding and so on)

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code. You miss something. Dynamically created content can't load existing `CSS` or `Js`. You should load `css` and `js` when you `click` the `button`. Just follow this way. I hope it will work with it well.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popoverTemplate.html">
        <div class="popover-line"> item 1</div>
        <div class="popover-line"> item 2</div>
        <div class="popover-line"> item 3</div>
        <style>
        .popover-content{
          display: block;
          width: 200px;
        }
        .popover-content .popover-line{
          background-color: #ff00ff;
          border-bottom: 2px solid #121212;
          padding: 10px 15px;
        }
        </style>
    </script>
```

If you write this way your custom `CSS` then it will work property. See the Image below how I write code.

[image]

> I hope it will help your project.